# Affine algebraic curve is Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

**The problem:**

*Let $P\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ be a non-constant polynomial with simple zeros. Show that the affine algebraic curve $X=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2\,:\,p(z)=w^2\}$ is a (connected) Riemann surface.*

**My progress so far:** Define $F(z,w)=w^2-p(z)$. Then $\nabla F(z,w)=(2w, -p^\prime(z))$. For $(z,w)\in X$, $w=0$ implies $p(z)=0$ and since the zeros are simple, $p^\prime(z)=0$, therefore the gradient is never zero and hence $X=F^{-1}(0)$ is a (real) submanifold.

**Questions:**

- Does this already imply that it is a Riemann surface (and if yes how, which theorem)?
- What is the complex structure?
- How do I show that it is connected?

If possible, please give an online available reference (some lecture notes maybe).

Comment: The (holomorphic) inverse function theorem can be used to establish a holomorphic atlas on $X$, just as in the smooth case.

Comment: So what I have done is enough to solve the exercise? What about the connectedness?

Comment: No, what you have done is not enough – unless you have proved the holomorphic version of the regular value theorem. A separate argument is needed for connectedness.

Comment: I can use the holomorphic version of the regular value theorem. So how do I argue for connectedness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question I already showed, that $X$ is a complex manifold. A Riemann surface which is determined by a polynomial is connected, if that polynomial is irreducible. To see that $F$ is irreducible, we can look at it as an element of the ring $R[w]$ where $R=\mathbb{C}[z]$. Let $z_0$ be a zero of $p$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(z-z_0)$. Then $p\in\mathfrak{p}$, but $p\not\in\mathfrak{p}^2$. By Eisenstein's criterion, $p$ is irreducible (over $R$ and therefore also as polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[z,w]$).

Comment: I think you are implicitly using Chow's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry#Chow.27s_theorem

It's pretty great and relates algebraic varieties to analytic varieties. Specifically your second sentence is the part that uses Chow as far as I can tell.